# How can we append an item at the beginning of sql query output

Tags: sql-server

Query:

```
select Names from TableName where (NameId < 4)
```

Output:
**Names**
Apple
Banana
Cat
Dog

Now I want to add new item "None" at the beginning of the above output and display it. Could someone help me out to do this.

**Names**
None<---
Apple
Banana
Cat
Dog

Comment: Look up Union for an easy solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UNION ALL` (`UNION` will work also, but it will return distinct values, so only use it if necessary)

```
SELECT 'None' as Names
UNION ALL
SELECT Names 
FROM TableName 
WHERE (NameId < 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'None'
union
select Names from TableName where (NameId < 4)
```